# Unable to scroll all the way to bottom of div

Tags: css, sharepoint, scroll, height, containers

I can't scroll all the way down to one of my DIVs. It happens only when I use my laptop. When I use my bigger screen everything works fine.

I have read that setting the height at 100% usually works but it does not for me.

here is a screenshot of the page https://postimg.org/image/j6kg868z3/

To provide a bit more context I am embedding this html on the body of a sharepoint page (i am branding sharepoint)and linking the css to the saved assets on our sharepoint server.

Here is the css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-width: 1414px !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: hi sorry about that, is that what you mean?

Comment: Did you read the link? you just gave us a few lines of CSS. We need a complete, verifiable replication of the issue.

Comment: remove "max-height:100%"

Answer (score 6):

```
max-height: calc(100vh - 120px) !important;
```

Try with this in your .wrapper class, you can also try with -100px or -80px, see what fits better for you, i had the same issue and by just decreasing that size on the max-height using calc worked great.

I know it's been a long time since you asked this, but i hope it helps anyway others

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to switch to using `vh` units for your `height` measurement. Get rid of `min-height` and `max-height`, and just add `height: 100vh;` to the `#wrapper`. You'll also want to make sure that the `#wrapper` doesn't have a `margin` or any `padding`.

> `1vh` is equal to 1% of the viewport window height. Learn more about CSS units [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-width: 1414px !important;
  color: white; /* Ignore */
  background: blue; /* Ignore */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">Content</div>
```

Comment: thank you. unfortanately it is still not scrolling all the way down, it actually goes down even less now.

Comment: @RichHomieNanz Can you post a link to your site, or create a CodePen / JSFiddle and post it here? You can also use Stack Overflow's built in code editor to post a working example.

Comment: so wierd i just put 50vh instead and now its working?

Comment: @RichHomieNanz That is weird. Like I said, 1vh is equal to 1% of the viewport window height. 100vh should be 100% of the window height, and 50vh should be 50% of the window height. Are you sure you had 100vh typed in initially, and not 10vh or 1vh?

Comment: ok so now that im looking at it, the div is still smaller and when i put 100vh the scroll bar gets very long and it wont scroll down all the way.

Comment: i didnt realize that when i put 50vh (and thought it worked), the div was actually thinner than before. i got overly excited

Comment: @RichHomieNanz Can you post a link to a working example or the site you're working on? It's hard to help you without more information.

Comment: If I change `height: 50vh` to `height: 100vh` in the JSFiddle, the wrapper touches the bottom of my browser, and I can scroll all the way down. Are you experiencing issues with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/haz6e9ek/) fiddle?

Comment: were you able to try it on a laptop with smalller screen?

Answer (score -1):

please try (**height:10vh**) instead of (**height:100%**). where vh stands for View Height.

Comment: It scrolls down but now it cuts the div to a smaller height, very thin.

Comment: oh! ok just add z-index:99999 !important then that may work fine or share your live output i'll check there

Comment: jsfiddle.net/sbmjL2o5/1